# Converter String com vários valores para arraylist e adicionar programaticamente em um spinner?

Tags: java, android

((Eu estou usando o navegador para entrar no site, pois app aqui tá com problema)

Eu estou puxando diversos resultados de formatos de  um vídeo no YouTube. Porém, quando passo para o spinner só passa um resultado, que geralmente é o primeiro, que geralmente é o áudio.  Então não aparece os formatos dos vídeos (restante) de todo resultado no spinner.

Editado:
Primeiro eu vejo se a app recebeu algum link válido do YouTube:

```
    // Check how it was started and if we can get the youtube link
    if (savedInstanceState == null && Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(getIntent().getAction())
        && getIntent().getType() != null && "text/plain".equals(getIntent().getType())) {

        String ytLink = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

        if (ytLink != null
            && (ytLink.contains("://youtu.be/") || ytLink.contains("youtube.com/watch?v="))) {
            youtubeLink = ytLink;
            // We have a valid link
            getUrl(youtubeLink);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    } else if (savedInstanceState != null && youtubeLink != null) {
        getUrl(youtubeLink);
    } else {
        //finish();
    }
}
```

Em seguida eu pego o link para converter e expandir a ação da app(formatos) e em seguida eu envio o resultado para um novo método pra que seja adicionado as opções de download no spinner:

```
private void getUrl(String youtubeLink) {
    new YouTubeExtractor(this) {
        @Override
        public void onExtractionComplete(SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles, VideoMeta vMeta) {
            if (ytFiles == null) {
                // Something went wrong we got no urls. Always check this.
                finish();
                return;
            }
            // Iterate over itags
            for (int i = 0, itag; i < ytFiles.size(); i++) {
                itag = ytFiles.keyAt(i);
                // ytFile represents one file with its url and meta data
                YtFile ytFile = ytFiles.get(itag);

                // Just add videos in a decent format => height -1 = audio
                if (ytFile.getFormat().getHeight() == -1 || ytFile.getFormat().getHeight() >= 360) {
                }
                    initSpinner(vMeta.getTitle(), ytFile);
                }
           }
    }.extract(youtubeLink, true, false);
}
```

Novo método para adicionar opções de *formato no spinner:

```
public void initSpinner(final String videoTitle, final YtFile ytfile){
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    // Display some buttons and let the user choose the format
    String opcFrmt = (ytfile.getFormat().getHeight() == -1) ? "Audio " +
        ytfile.getFormat().getAudioBitrate() + " kbit/s":
    ytfile.getFormat().getHeight() + "p";
    opcFrmt += (ytfile.getFormat().isDashContainer()) ? " dash" : "";

    // Spinner click listener
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //return the list representation of array

    strList.add(opcFrmt);
    strList.add(opcFrmt);

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, strList);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

O problema é que disso tudo só aparece um resultado no spinner.

Comment: Você apenas faz um `add` de uma `String` em `strList.add(opcFrmt);` logo tem sempre apenas um elemento. Onde estão os vários elementos que quer adicionar ?

Comment: Você está adicionando em sua 'strList' apenas uma string que é o 'opcFrmt'. 
Tem como editar a pergunta e mandar o resultado da variavel opcFrmt? Talvez seja necessário trabalhar essa variavel para que ela seja um array e não uma string. Assim, voce pode fazer um laço de repetição e adicionar todas as urls no 'strList'

Comment: Editado! Me ajudem por favor **

Comment: Na verdade este app trabalhava muito bem ao receber o resultado nesta String e adicionar em botões. Adicionava separadamente cada formato de boa. Button btn = new Button(this); btn.setText(opcFrmt);mainLayout.addView(btn);

Comment: Este segundo bloco de código é parte do método `initSpinner`? Se não, que método é esse?

Comment: Exatamente. O segundo bloco é o initSpinner.

Comment: Bloco de código editado**